# Как получить данные сайта и ввести их в переменную

Tags: android

Например: на определенном канале **youtube** есть  5.780 подписчиков. У меня есть переменная:

```
int sup = 0;
```

Как мне заносить число подписчиков в эту переменную в реальном времени?

Comment: Очень много разных вариантов даже по получению данных с сайта. Задавайте более конкретные вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой и неправильный вариант: каждые n минут/секунд скачивать HTML код страницы канала, найти там HTML тэг, содержащий кол-во подписчиков.

Сложный и правильный: почитать доки API youtube-а и узнать как это у них можно сделать.